# Convert stock ticker data to OHLC in PHP

Tags: php

There are quite a few questions regarding this in other languages but I couldn't find anything in PHP. I've this `$trades` array with columns amount, price and time:

```
$trades = array(
  array(87.23,  97.14,  "2018-10-04 03:53:37"),
  array(376.81, 100.16, "2018-10-04 01:36:56"),
  array(343.17, 97.67,  "2018-10-04 01:26:17"),
  array(291.31, 97.99,  "2018-10-04 00:12:2"),
  array(60.47,  96.42,  "2018-10-03 18:08:30"),
  array(353.18, 94.04,  "2018-10-03 14:30:24"),
  array(490.11, 99.06,  "2018-10-03 11:24:48"),
  array(377.52, 96.06,  "2018-10-03 06:05:31"),
  array(99.04,  100.71, "2018-10-03 04:19:53"),
  array(339.67, 96.17,  "2018-10-03 02:35:42"),
  array(195.14, 94.93,  "2018-10-03 02:24:55"),
  array(230.45, 95.08,  "2018-10-02 15:29:07")
);
```

I thought grouping the inner arrays by `day` and finding the first, max, min and last `price` value within each group will give desired Open, High, Low, Close entries for each day. I tried to group, but getting error.

```
 foreach ($trades as $trade) {
  $trade[2] = date('m d', strtotime($trade[2]));
}

$tradeGrouped = array();
foreach ($trades as $trade) {
  $tradeGrouped[$trade[2]] = $trade;
}
```

What I want is something like:

```
$ohlc = array(
  array("10-02", 95.08, 95.08, 95.08, 95.08),
  array("10-03", 100.71, 100.71, 94.04, 96.42)
  array("10-04", 97.99, 100.16, 97.14, 97.14)    
);
```

Comment: If you are getting this data from a RDBMS (like MySQL), you could do this much easily at the database level, rather than juggling with looping and arrays in PHP.

Comment: "getting error"? What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

By using `$tradeGrouped[$trade[2]]` you only keep the last value for each date.

This creates an array with a number of trades for each date:

```
$groups = [];

foreach ($trades as $trade) {
    $date = date('m d', strtotime($trade[2]));
    // Use this to handle dates from multiple years.
    // $date = substr($trade[2], 0, 10);

    if (!array_key_exists($date, $groups)) {
        $groups[$date] = [];
    }

    $groups[$date][] = $trade;
}
```

This creates the groups directly without altering the input.

Comment: Not tested by me either, but looks good to me. Not altering the input is certainly important if OP wants to get first and last values for each day.

Comment: Also, not necessarily saying you should include this in your answer, but OP will probably want to include the year in the group key so the dates will be sorted properly around the new year.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I kept the conversion as in the question, but I agree the year should be included to handle input from multiple years.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it [here on Online PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31a9c7626e00156d16660ded9af4acb1f9e60892) and output doesn't seem to be what I wanted (it spits out only the last array for each day). Could you have a look and maybe help  me get the desired OHLC in form [10 04, O, H, L, C], [10 04, O, H, L, C] ... ? @Kwebble